# How to echo out sequential numbers?

Tags: php

what I have is a number of various places in a class that calls out a number depending on a total number given and I would like to echo out that number. So for example:

Total count may be 4.

here is what may output:

```
echo "Layer-1" and "Color-1";
```

some additional coding... then call the same number again elsewhere in the code

```
echo "Placement-1";
```

some more coding... blah, blah

```
echo "FinalArt-1";
```

Then the loop starts again, only instead of -1 it is -2, and -3 and so on until the final number, in this case 4 has been satisfied.

Can anyone help on this? Newbie, in the house :/

Comment: "what I have is a number of various places in a class that calls out a number depending on a total number given and I would like to echo out that number." \*baffled\* Describe the inputs to your program, and the desired outputs. Don't try to explain how you think it'll work. Also, show us what you tried so far and describe the problem(s) that you encountered.

Comment: -1 for asking a question which is related to a scripting language without reading the first 5 chapters on any available tutorial

Comment: @fyr at least he did label as php, so we know what scripting language it is

Comment: for this tag i give him a hint

Comment: While you did receive an answer to what I _think_ you are asking, your question is really too unclear. If you can improve it, please flag your question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reference to a for - loop (here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

the first example in this reference is:

```
/* example 1 */

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

1. `$i <= 10` need to be adjusted by you
2. echo $i; will output 1..10 in the example (also needs to be replaced by you)